# Create a new button to change the state of new student

Tags: python, odoo

I am having a problem creating a new button to change the state of a new student.

First I created an XML file:

```
...
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="student_form">
<field name="name">sim.student.form</field>
<field name="model">sim.student</field>
<field name="type">form</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<form string="Student">
<field name="name"/>
<field name="student_name"/>
<field name="father_name"/>
<field name="gender"/>
<field name="contact_no"/>
<button name="setuju" states="draft" string="Approve" type="object"/>
</form>
</field>
</record>
...
```

Next I created a Python file:

```
from osv import fields, osv
import time
import netsvc
import pooler

class sim_student(osv.osv):
    _name = "sim.student"
    _description = "Data Siswa"

    def setuju(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        workflow = netsvc.LocalService('workflow')

        for name in ids:
            workflow.trg_create(uid, self._name, name, cr)

        return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'confirmed'}, context=context)

    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Registration Number',size=256,required=True),
        'student_name': fields.char('Student Name',size=256,required=True),
        'father_name': fields.char('Father Name',size=256),
        'gender':fields.selection([('male','Male'),('female','Female')],'Gender'),
        'contact_no':fields.char('Contact Number',size=256),
        'state': fields.selection([('new', 'New'), \
                                    ('confirmed', 'Received'), \
                                    ('cancelled', 'Cancelled')], \
                                'Status', readonly=True, select=True)
    }

sim_student()
```

Then I createe an **init**.py file :

```
import sim
```

Finally I created an **openerp**.py file :

```
{
'name': 'Student Information Management',
'version': '0.1',
'category': 'Tools',
'description': """Data Siswa.""",
'author': 'Wasis Lukito',
'summary': 'Test, Test, dan Test',
'website': 'http://wasis.wordpress.com/',
'depends': ['base'],
#'init_xml': [],
#'update_xml': ['sim_view.xml'],
#'demo_xml': [],
#'installable': True,
'data': ['sim_view.xml',],
'css':['static/src/css/lunch.css'],
'demo': [],
'installable': True,
'application' : True,
'certificate' : '001292377792581874189',
'images': [],
}
```

When I executed the code, however, it produced this error message:

```
No handler found.
```

And this is the error from the console:

```
C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0alpha-20121206-000102\Server\server\.\pytz\tzinfo.py
:5: DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated
ERROR: couldn't create the logfile directory. Logging to the standard output.
2013-01-15 15:21:39,977 2136 ←[1;32m←[1;49mINFO←[0m ? openerp: OpenERP version 7
.0alpha-20121206-000102
2013-01-15 15:21:39,994 2136 ←[1;32m←[1;49mINFO←[0m ? openerp: addons paths: C:\
Program Files\OpenERP 7.0alpha-20121206-000102\Server\server\openerp\addons
2013-01-15 15:21:40,023 2136 ←[1;32m←[1;49mINFO←[0m ? openerp: database hostname
: localhost
2013-01-15 15:21:40,039 2136 ←[1;32m←[1;49mINFO←[0m ? openerp: database port: 54
32
2013-01-15 15:21:40,055 2136 ←[1;32m←[1;49mINFO←[0m ? openerp: database user: op
enpg
ERROR: couldn't create the logfile directory. Logging to the standard output.
2013-01-15 15:21:40,799 2136 ←[1;33m←[1;49mWARNING←[0m ? openerp.addons.google_d
ocs.google_docs: Please install latest gdata-python-client from http://code.goog
le.com/p/gdata-python-client/downloads/list
2013-01-15 15:21:41,548 2136 ←[1;37m←[1;41mCRITICAL←[0m ? openerp.modules.module
: Couldn't load module web
2013-01-15 15:21:41,568 2136 ←[1;37m←[1;41mCRITICAL←[0m ? openerp.modules.module
: unexpected indent (sim.py, line 10)
2013-01-15 15:21:41,585 2136 ←[1;31m←[1;49mERROR←[0m ? openerp.service: Failed t
o load server-wide module `web`.
The `web` module is provided by the addons found in the `openerp-web` project.
Maybe you forgot to add those addons in your addons_path configuration.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0alpha-20121206-000102\Server\server\.\opener
p\service\__init__.py", line 53, in load_server_wide_modules
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0alpha-20121206-000102\Server\server\.\opener
p\modules\module.py", line 414, in load_openerp_module
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0alpha-20121206-000102\Server\server\openerp\
addons\web\http.py", line 593, in wsgi_postload
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0alpha-20121206-000102\Server\server\openerp\
addons\web\http.py", line 482, in __init__
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0alpha-20121206-000102\Server\server\openerp\
addons\web\http.py", line 549, in _load_addons
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0alpha-20121206-000102\Server\server\.\opener
p\modules\module.py", line 133, in load_module
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0alpha-20121206-000102\Server\server\openerp\
addons\sim\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0alpha-20121206-000102\Server\server\openerp\
addons\sim\sim.py", line 10
     def setuju(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    ^
 IndentationError: unexpected indent
2013-01-15 15:21:41,849 2136 ←[1;32m←[1;49mINFO←[0m ? openerp.service.netrpc_ser
ver: starting NET-RPC service on 0.0.0.0:8070
2013-01-15 15:21:41,877 2136 ←[1;32m←[1;49mINFO←[0m ? openerp.netsvc: Starting 1
 services
2013-01-15 15:21:41,897 2136 ←[1;32m←[1;49mINFO←[0m ? openerp: OpenERP server is
 running, waiting for connections...
2013-01-15 15:21:41,913 2136 ←[1;32m←[1;49mINFO←[0m ? openerp.service.wsgi_serve
r: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
```

The error seems to come from "def setuju(...". What is wrong with my script?

Comment: I tried your given code and its working without giving any error. Can you provide error coming on console.

Comment: i using windows, i don't know if it working in linux, how to provide an error from console (cmd)..?

Comment: i use openerp 7 alpha, i really blanks with this problem..

Comment: i've edited it with error message from console, what must i do now..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the key 'certificate' from the openerp file If your module doens't have a certificate. Also please remove the workflow from the `setuju()` function. I dont see a workflow defined for your class.

From the log the error is because indentation error. Please check you have correct number of spaces before `def setuju()`

Comment: i've edited it with error message from console, what must i do now..?

Comment: i do your command, then i get new error..

  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0alpha-20121206-000102\Server\server\openerp\
addons\sim\sim.py", line 8
     workflow = netsvc.LocalService('workflow')
            ^
 IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: @ws_123, as DReispt said, please remove tab and give spaces.

Comment: thanks, i can't believe it the error is because i used "tab" button..
unbelieved openerp...
thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To develop on OpenERP, even if have experience with it, you will frequently find situations like this. It's a *must* to learn know where your log files are check them for errors.

This will depend on how you installed the server, but according to the [documentation](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/install/windows/server/index.html#monitoring-the-openerp-server) it should be on `C:\Program Files\OpenERP X.X\Server\openerp-server.log.`. If not, look it up in the server configuration file .

If you are serious about OpenERP development, I would advise you to:

1. Stop the server services and start it manually in a console terminal instead. Not only it gives you instant information on warnings and errors, but it will also display the results from python `print` statements and let you go into `(Pdb)` [debug mode](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/debugging-in-python/).
2. Install your [OpenERP server in an Ubuntu Server](http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2012/12/how-to-install-openerp-7-0-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) VM. It may have a learning curve to use Linux, but there's a lot of help available, and in the long run you will find a lot easier to get help and solve troubles in that platform.

Comment: i've edited it with error message from console, what must i do now..?

Comment: `CRITICAL: unexpected indent (sim.py, line 10)` Check if you have tabs instead of spaces.

Comment: This is talking about how to locate the error, not how to solve it.